# Tap Titan boss killed my hero. stuck with 24 hours cooldown. What is the most advantageous action, time-wise?

Tags: tap-titans

In Tap Titans, when you take too long to kill a boss, he might slay one of your heroes. This hero then revives after a very long cooldown, but while any of your heroes are dead, your relics per prestige are halved.

This is a huge penalty, and most people just think they should stop playing for a day and then prestige after the hero has revived.

But honestly, going cold turkey for a whole day is too much. I think you are losing on more relics this path than the others.

Some of the choices available when a hero dies are:

- Use premium currency to bring the hero back to life immediately. Since premium currency have a real-world monetary cost, this is not useful in the long run.
- Wait the cooldown to run out. You can keep grinding (risking more hero death and losing that hero's powerups for the rest of that gameplay) but it is just a matter of time until you hit a wall and cannot progress any further. And grinding the wall has a huge risk of hero death.
- Cut your losses, and prestige right away. You begin a new game, get whatever relics you earned (without the "full team" bonus).

For this question, lets assume efficiency means relics / hour. You could measure relics per hour of real-world time, or relics per hour of gameplay.

What is the most efficient way to deal with hero death, the one that has the least efficiency loss?